# golang db.ping()

Tags: sql, go, ping

`db.ping()` function takes about 2s to return a error if db gone offline while execution of programe. is there any way to reduce that time taken

Comment: what is your db driver ?

Comment: With [PingContext](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.PingContext) of course. Cancel the context to abort the ping early. Support for cancelation may not be supported by all drivers.

Comment: actually no although context time expired PingContext also doesn't throw exception. it also try to build up connection about 2s

Answer (score 2):

Really no,

If you are waiting for a successful `ping` to happen before executing operations against the db then that's the price you have to pay!

It entirely depends on which db, which library, what's the network like etc.

From a top level, you could re-architect so that db healthchecks are not performed during user requests and then it won't really matter that the healthcheck is slow!

Or a more aggressive approach would be to add timeouts. If you know that a success ping takes `20ms` then add a `40ms` or `50ms` timeout to the operation, and consider that to be a failure! Fail fast!

Answer (score 0):

I used `go-sql-driver/mysql` library: 
https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

has this configuration options

- TimeOut
- ReadTimeOut
- WriteTimeOut

by changing its values actually in my case `TimeOut`. I could reduce timeOut time to user defined time

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the mysql bad connection error

```
func checkPing(db *sql.DB, globalConf string) *sql.DB {
   for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    err := db.Ping()
    if err == nil {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("mysql connection failed!", err)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
        log.Print("Retrying to make mysql connection...")
        /* mysql connection */
        db := connectToMysql(globalConf) // making reconnection..
        return db
    }
  }
return db                                                               
}
```

Comment: The question was about reducing the time for `db.ping()` to timeout. How does this address the question?